# Update ListView by TextChanged Event in Searchbar using Xamarin MVVM Prism

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, prism

I'm using MVVM Prism in Xamarin Forms. I'm accessing an API to GET records and I'm assigning it to an ObservableCollections.

I'm trying to figure out how to work my TextChanged EventToCommandBehavior on my SearchBar. The event trigger is working, what I'm trying to fix is the automatic update of my ListView while typing. I can do this when using the code behind, but now I want to use the MVVM Prism approach and put all my codes in my View Model.

I also tried creating ListView in my ViewModel and pass my ObservableCollection to it so I can use it as bindable object in my View but it is also not working, or maybe I am doing it wrong.

VIEW MODEL

```
 public class CoinsPageViewModel : BindableBase
        {
            public ObservableCollection<CoinsModel> coinsModel { get; set; }
            private ICoins _icoins;
            public INavigationService NavigationService { get; set; }

            private DelegateCommand<string> _textChangedCommand { get; set; }
            public DelegateCommand<string> TextChangedCommand => 
                _textChangedCommand ?? (_textChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(TextChanged));
    
            private async void TextChanged(string obj)
            {
                var coins = await _icoins.GetCoinsList();
                var keyword = _searchText;
                var searchResult = coinsModel.Where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));
                
                //----DISPLAY SEARCH RESULT TO THE BINDABLE OBJECT IN VIEW----
            }
    
            public CoinsPageViewModel(ICoins coins, INavigationService navigationService)
            {
                coinsModel = new ObservableCollection<CoinsModel>();
                _icoins = coins;
                LoadCoins();
                NavigationService = navigationService;
            }
    
            private string _searchText;
            public string SearchText
            {
                get { return _searchText; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _searchText, value); }
            }
    
            public async void LoadCoins()
            {
                var coins = await _icoins.GetCoinsList();
                foreach (var coin in coins)
                {
                    coinsModel.Add(coin);
                }
            }
    
            private CoinsModel _selectedCoin;
            public CoinsModel SelectedCoin
            {
                get { return _selectedCoin; }
                set 
                { 
                    _selectedCoin = value;
                    if (_selectedCoin != null)
                    {
                        var navigationParamaters = new NavigationParameters();
                        navigationParamaters.Add("coinsid", _selectedCoin.Id);
                        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("CoinsDetailsPage", navigationParamaters);
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }
```

VIEW

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
            <Grid>
                <StackLayout>
                    <SearchBar TextColor="White" 
                               Text="{Binding SearchText}"
                               BackgroundColor="#6b120a" 
                               Placeholder="Search" 
                               PlaceholderColor="White" 
                               CancelButtonColor="White">
                        <SearchBar.Behaviors>
                            <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged"
                                                          Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}"
                                                          CommandParameter="Text">
                            </prism:EventToCommandBehavior>
                        </SearchBar.Behaviors>
                    </SearchBar>
    
                    <ListView SeparatorColor="#d96818" 
                              x:Name="LvCoins"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding coinsModel}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCoin}"
                              Margin="5"                         
                              HasUnevenRows="True" 
                              androidSpecific:ListView.IsFastScrollEnabled="True">
                              
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                                        <StackLayout Margin="5,5,0,0">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                                   FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" 
                                                   FontFamily="Chunkfive"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Symbol}" 
                                                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                                   FontSize="15" TextColor="#6b120a" 
                                                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ContentPage.Content>
```

INTERFACE and MODEL

```
   public interface ICoins
        {
            Task<List<CoinsModel>> GetCoinsList();
            Task<CoinsDetailModel> GetCoinsDetails(string id);
        }

public class CoinsModel
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("symbol")]
            public string Symbol { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string NameSort => Name[0].ToString();
        }
```

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT82k.png)

Comment: "I also tried creating ListView in my ViewModel" - creating a UI element in your VM is not MVVM

Comment: you should create two copies of your data - one that is the "reference" copy, and a 2nd "filtered" copy that is bound to your UI.  When you search, update the "filtered" copy to only contain the matching elements of the "reference" copy

Comment: @Jason upon loading the main page. it is displaying all the data from the Web Api. So the ListView is binded to my ObservableCollection Model. if I’m going to bind the Ui to the filtered, it will not display all the list upon the first load of the page.

Comment: i’m thinking of creating a List, upon the initial load of the app, the data will be fetch from the api to my observablecollection, and will copy it also to a List. so in the TextChanged event, i will use the List to query Linq the searchbar text and finally move it again to observablecollection. hmm..

Comment: By default filtered should contain all of the data

Comment: @Jason my follow up question is, my searchResult in the TextChanged event is IEnumerable, how can I copy it to an ObservableCollection? Ibelieve you cannot cast IEnumerable to an ObservableCollection, or can we?

Comment: Just use a foreach to add the items

Comment: @error404 re-assigning `coinsModel` to a new OC doesn't hurt. Just do `coinsModel = ObservableCollection(ienumerableInstance)`

Answer (score 0):

I already found the best fix for this. I installed the NuGet package PropertyChanged.Fody and it fixed all my issues. I don't need to write SetProperty nor Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged at all. I also create a List which will be used by my Search event. Thank you all.

Comment: Have same issue. Can you share the code changes please